# Create contact belong to third-party Account?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I have an issue here. I possibly insert contact to Contact Provider but I wonder can I create an contact that belong to Third-Party Account.I mean: I want to add my contact belong to Third-Party account instead of Google Account. I find some apos in Google Play(Facebook contact sync app,...), but they did not have this function. I think Google Contact Provider does not allow us to do this.  Can we do it and if it's possible , plz tell me how ?

Thank for your reading!

[image: create third party contact]

Answer (score 0):

While inserting a contact into RAW Contact table, provide A AccountType and accountName.

```
    final ContentProviderOperation.Builder newContact = ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
    newContact.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, rawContact.accountType);
    newContact.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, rawContact.accountName);
    newContact.withValue(RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE, RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE_DISABLED);
```